Defining functions as other functions
I'm writing a package that provides a new shortcut layout for Emacs. Among other things, I'd like to replace y-n-queries with queries using a and t. I know there is a map for most such queries, but a lot of functions have y-n-queries with some further options hard-coded in them, like recover-file. And since these functions are called by many other functions I have to actually replace them with variants in which the queries are coded differently. So I'm looking for the safest way to do that. With variables I've used a system where I back up the previous value of a variable, then overwrite it with my value when I start the mode of my package and overwrite the variable again with the backup value if I quit the mode. This way, the original value of the variable is always stored and the process is safe. So I'd like to do this again for the functions I'm defining, but for that I need to basically set a function to the value of another function. I can do something like
(defun recover-file (file)
  (funcall 'daselt-recover-file file))

to have recover-file call daselt-recover-file instead of what it usually does, but if I made a similar defun defining daselt-recover-file-backup as a call to recover-file and then used the above defun to redefine recover-file, then the backup would refer to the current value of recover-file and thus be useless. Ideally, I'd like to have something like set, but for functions instead of variables. Is there a way to do this?

Are you looking for fset?

Remember to back up first: (setq recover-file-backup (symbol-function 'recover-file))

I recommend that you use Advice.
Refer to: C-hig (elisp)Advising Functions
You would add the advice when your mode is enabled, and remove it when your mode is disabled.
This approach is far less brittle than storing function values in variables.  You would need nothing more than another piece of lisp code to be messing with the same function during an overlapping time period for your backup scheme to become badly broken, whereas advice can (I believe) be combined with relative safety.

I'm also not happy with the brittleness of the approach and I've thought about using advice, what kept me from it is that, if I, say, put a piece of advice around a function with a hard-coded y-n-query that temporarily remaps the keys, then that function still sends a message string to the user displaying the options with their keybinds, which would be the original keybinds, not those the user should use now that the keys have been remapped. Since that message goes directly to the user, is it even possible to intercept and modify it using advice?

Well you were talking about replacing a function with a different one, so I'm suggesting you do that (but using advice to do it).  I'm imagining you won't be calling the original function at all.

Ah, I see, that should work, thanks!

For clarity, nadvice.el provides an :override type of advice for this purpose.

Thanks to NickD and shynur I found what I was looking for: I can use symbol-function to define a variable storing the function definition associated to a backup symbol, then set the function in question to the function definition of its daselt-analogue using fset, and later on restore the original function definition by reading it from the symbol where it is stored.

C-h f defalias
